# Getting the name of a Bluetooth device with Apples "External Accessory framework"

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have to build an App that can get the name of a Bluetooth device.
The device is an Apple compliant one.

Is it possible to get the name of an Apple compliant Bluetooth device with Apples "External Accessory framework"?

If so, please let me know, so that I have an idea how to solve this.

Best regards, Jennifer

Comment: EAAccessory class has various properties, one of them is name https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessory_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008196.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`EAAccessory`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessory_class/Reference/Reference.html)'s [`name`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessory_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008196-CH1-SW6) property.

Code Sample:

```
NSArray *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] 
                        connectedAccessories]; 
EAAccessory *accessory = nil; 

for (EAAccessory *obj in accessories)
{ 
    NSLog(@"Found accessory named: %@", obj.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam.
One additional question: This will only work for Apple compliant devices, true? Have you ever tried this on normal Bluetooth devices (to get their name)?